# Where does the extra 'D' come from in dup1.go?

Tags: go

I'm new to golang and learning it now. I'm reading "The Go Programming Language" book and trying to run the dup1 example on my Mac. But I noticed a very weird issue. The output of the count contains an extra "D". Anyone has any idea why?

```
> go run dup1New.go                                                                                                                                test
test
test
hello
hello
world
3D      test
2   hello
> cat dup1New.go                                                                                                                                   
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    counts := make(map[string]int)
    input := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for input.Scan() {
        counts[input.Text()]++
    }
    // NOTE: ignoring potential errors from input.Err()
    for line, n := range counts {
        if n > 1 {
            fmt.Printf("%d\t%s\n", n, line)
        }
    }
}
```

go version go1.13.5 darwin/amd64

Comment: I do not have that extra 'D' in my output. How are you "closing" the input (what do you do when you want to end entering inputs)?

Comment: Same here, no D. To end the input you have to type ctrl-d. Do you have the same result when executing the program again ?

Comment: I used ctrl-d to end my input.

Answer (score 3):

As [wlisrausr answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59625072/1256452), this is in part from your MacOS Terminal `stty` settings.  (You probably should not turn off `echoctl`, though.)

To be more complete: when you type the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> sequence to signal EOF,<sup>1</sup> the [tty driver](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596005903/ch18.html)<sup>2</sup> "displays" the character as the two-character sequence `^D`, but then prints two *backspace* or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> characters.  More precisely, it does so as long as the `ECHOCTL` flag is set in the `lflags` control field in the underlying tty settings.

The window that is displaying the interactive Terminal session is treating output as *directives* to draw particular characters, move (position) the cursor, and have other interesting effects.  Some character codes, particularly those in the range `0x20` (32 decimal) through `0x7e` (126 decimal), are *displayable* [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters.  Others are controlling characters—[ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)—or [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters that have been encoded in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).  Go itself uses UTF-8 extensively, to encode [runes](https://blog.golang.org/strings), so Go's use of UTF-8 dovetails nicely with Terminal's use of UTF-8.<sup>3</sup>

The <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, ASCII code 8—which they call BACKSPACE or BS—has the effect of moving the [cursor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(user_interface)) back one display-column.  That is, it is a cursor-positioning control code.  (There are many of these; see the ANSI escape codes page.  This stuff has a very long history, going back to just after the first [glass tty](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/G/glass-tty.html).)

So, the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> has been displayed as `^D`, but the *cursor* is positioned over the `^` (hat or caret or circumflex) character.  Now you, in your Go program, send to the Terminal display-handling code, a sequence of ASCII codes: `3`, which is 0x33 or 51 decimal; then <kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or ASCII Horizontal Tab (HT), which is code 9; then the ASCII codes for the letters `test` (0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74), then a newline or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> or ASCII NL, which is code 10.

Like backspace, a horizontal tab is a *cursor positioning* operation.  It directs the terminal (or window emulation of terminal) to move the cursor to the next tab-stop, without changing anything else on the display.  So you first overwrite the `^` with `3`, leaving `3D` visible, and the cursor positioned over the letter `D`.  Then you have Terminal move the cursor to column 9 (columns are numbered from 1 and the default tab stop is at every eighth column) and display the word `test`, and then move the cursor to column 1 of a new line.  The result is that the line shows:

```
3D      test
```

(with exactly six blank positions between `D` and the first `t`).  On the newly exposed or created line, which is currently all-blank, you print the character `2`, move to column 9, and print the letters `hello` (and another newline directive).

---

<sup>1</sup>In fact, control-D simply pushes the accumulating line through the "input canonization" queue as is.  If the line is *empty*, this sends a zero-length record up the tty's read side.  Reading zero bytes from a file or device-file is *interpreted as* EOF by many systems, including Go's `os.File` reader.  If you type a partial line, without a terminating newline, and then use control-D to send it, you can no longer edit that partial line, and a reader that is reading and is not concerned with newlines will have obtained the data and be using it at this point.  A second control-D is then required to signal the EOF: the reader simply got the non-newline terminated input from the first control-D.

<sup>2</sup>This link describes Linux tty drivers, but Linux tty drivers are derived from the same common ancestor behind MacOS tty drivers.

<sup>3</sup>This is not an accident, even though the Go folks are not the Darwin folks: again, all this stuff goes back (via different paths) to some common ancestors.

Comment: Wow. This is a very bright & clear explanation. Should be accepted as the answer. Thanks bro.

Comment: BIG THANKS to @torek. Very detail and clear explanation. Learned a lot from it!!!

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that `D` character from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is because of `echoctl` option in your terminal device interface. You could easily remove that off by running this command in your shell/terminal:

```
stty -echoctl
```

Ref: `man stty`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works. Just curious why the extra 'D' only in "%d\t%s\n" output but not "%d %s\n".

Comment: Probably related to that `tab` character. I'm not really sure though. Hehe